# How to make visible all of the widgets from a single line(RowTable)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have written is code below, but button isn't shown because i've set FILL_PARENT in bar layoutParametrs. How i could fixed it without using XML?

```
    TableRow        myLayout    = new TableRow      (this);
    myLayout.setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);
    TextView        text        = new TextView      (this);
        text.setText("Test: ");
    SeekBar         bar         = new SeekBar       (this);
    ToggleButton    button      = new ToggleButton  (this);
    myLayout.addView(   text    , new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myLayout.addView(   bar     , new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myLayout.addView(   button  , new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

If FILL_PARENT set for bar

[image: If FILL_PARENT set for bar]

If isn't

[image: If not set]

both variant is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to fill a row with multiple items, I typically use layout_weight and a width setting of fill_parent.  That distributes the full width of the row by the proportions for which you set the weight values.

Since you're doing this in code and not xml, look at the constructor for LayoutParams that takes a third parameter.  This corresponds to layout_weight:

[LayoutParams - int, int, float](http://bit.ly/f9kbhM)

Answer (score 1):

Try using WRAP_CONTENT and a weight parameter like this.

```
myLayout.addView(   text    , new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,5));
myLayout.addView(   bar     , new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10));
myLayout.addView(   button  , new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,85));
```